# what is the difference between array[1][2] and array[1,2]?

Tags: c, arrays, linux

if my two dimensional array is int array[4][5]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

when I print a position: printf("%d\n",array[2,0]);. this is printing the address of the value without giving the &. but if I print like this: printf("%d\n",&array[2][0]); it is printing address of the value. As I have given the & it prints the address. but both the address are different. but if I print printf(",:%d\n",array[3,0]); it is printing the same address of array[2,0].

what is the difference between [2][0] and [2,0] accessing the array elements.

Comment: by seeing the usage of `printf()` it looks more like a `C` question. so why tag `C++`? Though, the context is valid in both the cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read about comma operator.
`array[2][0]` is accessing element at third row, first column.
`array[2,0]` is first executing operation `(2,0)` (which returns 0) and thus is equivalent to `array[0]`, which returns the first row of array (actually `&array[0][0]` because it decays to a pointer).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now I have cleared idea about that.

Answer (score 4):

Using `array[1,2]` is just an example of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) being misused -> `1, 2` evaluates both operands and yields `2` -> you are accessing `array[2]`.

---

Side note: `array` is not a good name for an array given [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: I fail to see how `std::array` could clash with this name (short of universally discouraged `using namespace std;`).

Comment: @Griwes Why tempt fate? Plus, "array" doesn't say anything about the **purpose** of the object. It is always good to name variables according to their meaning, not according to their internal structure.

Comment: Sure, the name is poor, but sometimes "array" is just what it is (I use names like that if I need such an array to init another object that must, say, be looped over to init, for example).

Answer (score 2):

`2, 0` invokes the so-called comma operator which **discards the value of all expressions which occur before the last comma** and represents the value of the expression on the very right. 
Hence `array[2, 0]` is equivalent to `array[0]`, and the array-to-pointer decay yields the address of the element at position 0 in `array[0]` - that is equivalent to `&array[0][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

`array[2,0]` doesn't do what you think it should. It only has a single index, which is the expression `2,0`. That is, it's equivalent to `array[(2,0)]`. This expression involves the comma operator, which evaluates each of its operands, and the result of which is the result of the last operand. So in your case, it's equivalent to `array[0]`. This denotes the first of your "inner" arrays, which when you try to print it, undergoes array-to-pointer conversion and gives you a pointer to the start of that array.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is treating `arr[3,0]` as `arr[0]`. This is how comma operator works.

And that's why `arr[3,0] and arr[2,0]` both are printing the same address because both would resolve to base address i.e arr[0].

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference between array[1][2] and array[1,2]?

The difference is a pretty big thing.

the first example is an multidimensional array access.

you are accessing the 2nd's elements value of the first array.

The second case is just a 1 dimensional array, where the index is invoked with a comma operator within.
This would be, the cpu has to take the 1, discard all operations amde with it when encoutnering the `,` and after that taking the `2`.

So the second case just accesses the 2nd elements value of a 1 dimensional array.

For better udnerstanding you should read this:

[What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/2003898)

Answer (score 0):

For better readability, you can rewrite your array definition as

```
array[4][5]= {
               1,2,3,4,5,             //a[0][0~4]
                6,7,8,9,10,            //a[1][0~4]
                11,12,13,14,15,        //a[2][0~4]
                16,17,18,19,20};       //a[3][0~4]
```

- `array[2,0]` is a single-level dereferencing using a single index, having a `,` [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).
- `array[2][0]` is a double-level dereferencing, using two indexes.

As per the definition of the `,` operator,

> the comma operator (represented by the token `,`) is a binary operator
>   that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then
>   evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

Now, saying `printf("%d\n",array[2,0]);.` get evaluated as `printf("%d\n",array[0]);`

Similarly,  `printf("%d\n",array[3,0]);` also gets evaluated to `printf("%d\n",array[0]);`

So, they end up producing same result.

On the other hand, `printf("%d\n",&array[2][0]);`, refers to the address of 1st element in the 3rd row. So it's different.

If you notice the data type, you'll find the difference easily.

- `array[0]` represents the data type of `int[5]`
- `array[2][0]` represents teh data type of `int`

Note: To print a pointer, you need to use `%p` format specifier, not `%d`.

Comment: You _almost_ got the initialization right. But anyway that doesn't answer the question: `what is the difference between [2][0] and [2,0] accessing the array elements.`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ please let me know which part needs more clarification. also, a bit about the _almost_ part, please.

Comment: You need to clarify abouit the comma operator, not just restate that the _value gets evaluated_. The initialization code looks correct now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you, edited my answer. please review it now.